# How to access cookie from view in PHP Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I can access cookie in controller then pass it to view

```
//HomeController.php
public function index(Request $request)
{
  $name = Cookie::get('name');
  return view('index', ['name'=> $name]);
}
```

But I want to write a small control (widget) that can fetch data from cookie without concern of parent controller. For example, *header, footer widgets* could fetch its own data without *main page controller* knowing which data is needed.

I can query the data from database by using View Composer. But, how can I access data from view in the request cookie ?

Comment: you want access data 'in the request cookie' not 'from the request cookie'

Answer (score 9):

Using static function with defining namespace and etc is a not safe.

Cuz maybe in next versions of framework this namespace can change.

It's better to use helper functions.

```
{{ request()->cookie('laravel_session') }}
```

or

```
{{ cookie('laravel_session') }}
```

Tested on working app with Laravel 5.2

Comment: FatalErrorException in 427dd709720c726a6d1a0c0d94dc843b line 1:
Call to undefined function request()

Comment: @Momo, it's working with 5.2, I've just tested it. cannot be.

Comment: Thanks, I am using Laravel 5.0, the cookie('laravel_session') did work.

Comment: Happy to help. Yes cookie() is very simple and comfortable.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `{{ Cookie::get('laravel_session') }}` to print out the cookie inside your view.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
{{\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::get('laravel_session')}}
```

in a blade template

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
 $response = new \Illuminate\Http\Response(view('your_view'));
 $response->withCookie(cookie('cookieName' , 'cookieValue' , expire));
 return $response;
```

or

```
 \Cookie::queue('cookieName', 'cookieValue', expire);
 return view('your_view');
```

I've used both of them.